# Align an image in div with text below

Tags: html, css

I've looked for a previous answer that helped me but couldn't find one.

HTML:

```
  <section id="pane_one">
    <h1 id="logo">lel</h1>
    <h2 id="hello"><span>Hello.</span> You&rsquo;ve reached my page.</h2>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
section#pane_one {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 450px;
    height: 700px;
}

h1#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 44.5%;
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-left: -33px;

    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/RMQi9Js.jpg') center center no-repeat;

    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid black;
}
```

How do I set it up so that no matter the zoom of the page, the div/image is always horizontally aligned with the text below it?

The site is: http://libeclipse.me/

Comment: @theblindprophet you are wrong on both accounts. Targeting with id and tag can have meaning if the id is applied to different elements in different pages and you need to style accordingly (*although you are right that on this specific snippet if there is not other context it is not required*). Also putting a space between them would target a `#logo` that was a descendant of `h1` not when it is on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `h1#logo` rule change the `left` to `50%` and the `margin-left` to `-100px`

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
section#pane_one {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 450px;
    height: 700px;
}

h1#logo {
position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 200px;
display: inline-block;
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/RMQi9Js.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid black;
}

h2#hello {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="pane_one">
    <h1 id="logo">lel</h1>
    <h2 id="hello"><span>Hello.</span> You&rsquo;ve reached my page.</h2>
  </section>
  </body>
<html>
```

Review this and make note of the margin:auto (Centered the h2text in absolute position) and display:inline-block(Centered the bunny image).

Removed the left % and margins that were present from h1#logo.
Enjoy.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The text is all overlapping at the top of the page.

Comment: The text should be below the div, not the other way around.

Comment: Have you tried changing the top:; attribute? Working with percentages carries its price.